# Check namespace

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, namespaces

I recently added a class I created with a tool to my Visual Studio 2010 project but I can't call it in my codebehind file. I was told I need to check the namespace. How do I check and control a classes's namespace?

Comment: You should go back and see if your old questions have answers to accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the code files:

```
Namespace Utilities

    Public Class Foo

    End Class

End Namespace

Namespace Utilities.Formatting

    Public Class DatesAndTimes

    End Class

End Namespace
```

Now, you have to make sure to add the following to any code page:

```
Imports Utilities
' and/or
Imports Utilities.Formatting
```

However, you can double-click on MyProject in the solution explorer in Visual Studio, and on the References tab, automatically Import the namespaces you want on all code pages without explicity typing "Imports " on every code page.